# Can using two different LocationListener's cause problems?

Tags: android, gps

I have two different classes in my application that implement LocationListener.  One of them is only used as needed to get the user's current location, while the other is constantly run in the background to keep data on the user's speed.

On my test device, this causes no problems.  Some other people testing however have said that their device "locks" (I have not seen this occur, so I'm unsure what they truly mean by this) when trying to acquire the location.

Is it possible that this is just their phone having a weak GPS fix, or could this be some weird hardware issue that occurs when two different threads are trying to gain the location via GPS?  If so, what's the best way to work around this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the new [fused provider](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) that is part of Google Play Services. I would not set two `LocationListeners`. Since you will be constantly tracking the user's location, by using the new `LocationClient` you can use its `getLastLocation()` to retrieve the most recent best, cached location the device has, which is really likely to be one from  the constant updates you are already retrieving. The fused provider will also determine which one is the best provider to take the location from, you do not need to worry about that logic.

Comment: Yeah this seems like it may be what I need to do.  I was trying to avoid it (Code was originally poorly designed, time consuming/work to merge the logic together) but it'll be better in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, it is probably the best way to go.